# How to use Postgresql JSON functions to flatten deeply nested data?

Tags: postgresql

Is it possible to use nested `jsonb_array_elements` functions in `FROM` clause to flatten json column with deeply nested data? Or is there some other way to do it without a subquery?

To elaborate the question let's have the following simple schema and data (here's the [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/b37b86/1/0)):

```sql
CREATE TABLE item_groups (id serial PRIMARY KEY, group_data jsonb);

INSERT INTO item_groups (group_data) VALUES ('{
  "items": [
    { "name": [{ "language": "en" }, { "language": "de" }] },
    { "name": [{ "language": "sv" }, { "language": "fi" }] }
  ],
  "colors": ["red", "blue", "green"]
}'::jsonb);
```

I know I can flatten the values with the following query using two nested `jsonb_array_elements` calls. However, I want to get all language and color combinations which I don't get here. I'd be also interested to know what is happening in the query, i.e., is Postgresql doing implicit INNER JOIN for lang and color or how the result is obtained?

```sql
SELECT jsonb_array_elements(jsonb_array_elements(group_data->'items')->'name')->>'language' AS lang,
       jsonb_array_elements_text(group_data->'colors') AS color
FROM item_groups;
```

I was able to construct the following query to flatten and filter the data but is there a way to do it in a more simple way without a subquery? This construct gets complex if the object is deeper.

```sql
SELECT l.lang, color
FROM item_groups,
     jsonb_array_elements_text(group_data->'colors') AS c(color),
     (
        SELECT jsonb_array_elements(item->'name')->>'language' AS lang
        FROM item_groups,
             jsonb_array_elements(group_data->'items') AS gd(item)
     ) l    
WHERE l.lang = 'en'
ORDER BY lang, color;
```

Comment: So what is the output you want?

Comment: I want to get all rows that have certain values in deeply nested properties. In the provided example that could be all rows having `language = 'en' AND color = 'red'`. In the real use case the values are deeper and the condition is more complex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PostgreSQL 12 provides new handy JSON functions and operators ([see docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/functions-json.html)) which can be used to simplify JSON queries. The query below gives the same result as the question's query which uses subqueries, but it is simpler especially if the object is deeper:

```sql
SELECT lang #>> '{}' AS lang,
       color #>> '{}' AS color
FROM item_groups,
     jsonb_path_query(group_data, '$.colors[*]') AS color,
     jsonb_path_query(group_data, '$.items[*].name[*].language[*]') AS lang
WHERE lang ? 'en'
ORDER BY lang, color;
```

However, if the actual target is not to flatten the nested data but to filter rows based on values in deeply nested properties (as I realized is my case after @a_horse_with_no_name's comment), a better solution is @a_horse_with_no_name's answer which disappeared soon after it was posted so I'm posting it here:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM item_groups
WHERE group_data @@ '$.items[*].name[*].language == "en"'
  AND group_data @> '{"colors":["red"]}';
```